# im getting a geofencing reuest error using HERE api

Tags: here-api

```
{"faultCode":"s73552fd8-9c05-4bbd-a929-359aadde38c6","responseCode":"400","message":"The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters. They must both be passed as query parameters. If you do not have app_id and app_code, please obtain them through your customer representative or at http://developer.here.com/myapps."}
```

I use just the API key. I don't have an app_id and app_code

Answer (score 1):

check the new HERE domain for the apikey from here and try-

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geofencing/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

If you are using api key than for geofencing api request basedUrl should be `https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com.`

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: are there any changes in uploading geofence in 2021 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Add the core legacy libraries.